# Path to the configuration files of libreoffice from the command line

Tags: bash, libreoffice

I use to run **libreoffice** headless for executing some macros from a **bash** script:

```
soffice --headless "$year_to_process"/"$initials".ods macro:///Standard.C69.MergeSaveClose
```

Before I do that, I need to check if the macro file `c69.xba` is present in the directory `$HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/Standard/`.

The problem is that the digit '4' above seems to me to be version dependant. Another problem is that that digit doesn't match exactly the major version number returned by `libreoffice --version`, which outputs:

> LibreOffice 5.4.5.1 40m0(Build:1)

What I have coded so far is:

```
# check the macro .config/libreoffice/*/user/basic/Standard/c69.xba is present
[ -f $HOME/.config/libreoffice/*/user/basic/Standard/c69.xba ] || {
    echo "$cmd: missing file basic/Standard/c69.xba"
    exit 1
}
```

using a '*' to match any version, but when a second directory will appear, as `.config/libreoffice/{4,5}/user/basic/Standard`, my code will no longer work.

My question is: how can I get (from the command line) the correct path to the directory containing the macros used by the current version of libreoffice, without using a '*'?

Comment: Do you know how your config folder is correlated to your version number ? Does a version `LibreOffice 5.4.5.1` mean you'll have a `$HOME/.config/libreoffice/5` folder ?

Comment: In my case, however using LibreOffice 5, the configuration files are in `$HOME/.config/libreoffice/4`. The settings are visible from the GUI from the menu *Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Paths*  I use a very recent fresh install of my system. So I don't think this is a legacy of a previous installation under LibreOffice 4. My conclusion was that the correlation between LibreOffice and the config folder must be hard coded. But who knows?

Comment: Yeah, taken from [the documentation](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile), the path seems to be arbitrary without any real correlation :/ You could do a case statement in combination with `eval $(which libreoffice) --version` or assume the user uses a recent enough version and hardcode `4` in your script.

Comment: @PierreFrançois: How is the mapping done between the version of `libreoffice` to the `.xba` file? so do you mean, if `libreoffice --version` returns a string containing `4` we need to look up file under that folder? and similarly others?

Comment: @Aserre: thank you for the suggestion, but the script is not intended to be interactive. I am looking in the direction of taking the least recently created profile.

Comment: @PierreFrançois: Also note that there are a couple of issues `*` inside a double-quote will be treated literally. Also `*` does not do a recursive glob

Comment: @Inian: yes, thank you, I just noticed it, and I had to take the double quotes away. I will edit my post in that sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the comment above of [Aserre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057091/aserre) about the arbitrary character of the path to the configuration of LibreOffice, I chose to select the most recently created profile of LibreOffice, using the `-t` option of the `ls` command. So I found next solution to work:

```
# check the macro .config/libreoffice/*/user/basic/Standard/c69.xba is present
path=$(ls -dt "$HOME"/.config/libreoffice/* | head -n1) # take only first line of output of ls -dt
[ -f "$path/user/basic/Standard/c69.xba" ] || {
    echo "$cmd: missing file basic/Standard/c69.xba"
    exit 1
}
```